# Angular8 using capacitor application failed to login from android studio

Tags: java, android, angular, angular8, capacitor

I am using

```
angular 8 
nativescript 6.8.0 
typescript 3.5.3 
"@capacitor/android": "2.4.0",
"@capacitor/cli": "^2.4.2",
"@capacitor/core": "^2.4.2",
```

ng serve    --  webapp is working fine  login also working fine and able connect backend login REST API

npx cap server   -- also working fine on http://localhost:3333/

I follow https://capacitorjs.com/  to convert my webapp to android app but
npx cap open android --- able to open app on android studio but not able to login and also not able to dubug properly because i am not java and android developer expert can any one guide how to proceed and  where i am going wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Add this in Your manifest in application tag

`cleartextTrafficPermitted="true"`

Comment: android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"   try this but still not solved, i am using domain name for backed REST API call

Comment: WoW !  its working without above parameter but i changed DNS name to IP